# Joomla and Moodla XML-RPC Error (404)

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomdle

I'm working on doing integration between `Moodle 2.x` and `Joomla 2.5.x` using the `Joomdle`, but when user try to register in the joomla, the system show this error message

```
XML-RPC Error (404): Unknown error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem after upgrading the joomdle.

You can check the following post-
http://www.joomdle.com/wiki/Upgrading

> Remove old auth/joomdle folder and put new one in place Visit Moodle
>   Notifications Go to Administration -> Plugins-> Web Services ->
>   External Services, select Joomdle and go to Functions, to add any new
>   one that the new version may have.

The part I was missing is to add functions.And because of this I was getting `XML-RPC Error (404): Unknown error`.

I followed this- 
Plugins->External Services->Joomdle->Functions->add 
and select all functions started from joomdle as shown in below post.

http://www.joomdle.com/wiki/Installing_Joomdle_in_Moodle_2#Add_functions_to_service

Hope this will help someone.